# Whitespace in an container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, whitespace, col

I am currently new in bootstrap5 and i am having whitespace problems on my left side when its on full screen its all fine but when I am testing responsiveness the whitespace on the image never leaves. [image]

I have tried the overflow and setting height and width but it still doesn't occupy it. help is highly appreciated as i am new with Bootsrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="supertest.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid g-0 m-0 p-0 ">
        <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-8 g-0 m-0 p-0">
                <img src="backgroundleft.jpg" alt="leftbg" class="img-fluid h-100 w-100">
            </div>

            <div class="col-4 overflow-hidden d-flex flex-column">
            
                <div class="text-center pt-5 mb-2">
                <img src="PUPLogo.png" alt="" class="w-25">
                </div>
                <h1 class="text-center">Reg<span>iTech</span></h1>
                <h2 class="px-5">Login</h2>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group px-5 mb-3">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group px-5">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn w-50 ">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>

                  <div class="mt-3 text-center">
                    don't have an account yet ?
                  </div>
                <div class="row text-center mt-auto">
                    <div class="copyright">
                        Copyright@2022 | RegiTech | Developed DICT 3-1
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>





    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want image as background cover?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I need the image to fill the left side of the div

Comment: You probably want a background image and not an image tag. Unsure how you want the image to fill the space, it will get distorted.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue. Your code snippet shows nothing like the image you shared.

Answer (score 0):

One solutions could be to remove the image as an elements and add it as a background image via CSS to style the container itself. Then, using some aspect ratio magic with `object-fit: cover;` You should be able to set a responsive background image which scales.

Example Here: https://jsfiddle.net/fatchild/r70gLwu3/53/

The idea is that you want the container to never show white space so you set the background image of that container to the image and make sure the image is 100 viewport width and height. This might cause the image to distort if it was forced to be the height and width of the container. To remedy this, the object-fit declaration will make sure the most appropriate part of the image is shown without distorting the aspect ratio or causing white space.

1. Remove the img element
2. Add new id to the container element `id="bg-img"`
3. Set some new declarations for that id attribute

---

```
#bg-img {
   object-fit: cover;
   background-image: url("http://uniacco.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/shutterstock_1062917057.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Remember that local resources will not render on other peoples machines. So when posting an example make sure to link a random image from the internet, as you it will render on other people's local machines when they try to run your code.